# Stack two circles relatively positioned in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Can anyone help me to realize this kind of circles with foundation[image]:

I am so hopeless. These circles must be responsive.

Comment: What have you tried? Can it be a pure CSS solution, since I have no clue what Foundation is and how it works?

Comment: It can be a pure css solution. I tried to make a div with border radius etc. Thats great. But when i try to stack the second circle above the other its crash my page...

Comment: are those circles empty or they need to contain something?

Comment: The big circle get Text and the small circle just a background image.

Comment: Its considered really bad to post a question without showing us what you have tried. This can be interpreted as you saying: "Make this work for me" or "Create this". Please don't ask questions without showing what your having problems with.

Comment: Hey Persijin, yeah you´re right. But thats not really my intent. I forgot to post the code and 5 minutes later Manoj and Fabrizio post their solutions. I  added their code to my code and fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting a pure CSS approach as you asked in comments.

1. Position the `.small-circle` absolutely to the relatively positioned
   `.big-circle`.
2. Let the `width` and `height` of the big circle be in viewport sized units.
3. Use `%` for the `left` and `top` values in the smaller circle.

```css
.big-circle {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #70AAD4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* For presentation */
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.small-circle {
  background: #70aad4 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 33%;
  left: -5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.cbig {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5%;
}
.csmall {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbig">
  <div class="csmall"></div>
</div>
```